# How is 0.0 typically represented in the absence of subnormals?

Tags: floating-point, zero, subnormal-numbers

The inclusion of subnormal numbers in IEEE 754 was a controversial decision.
In floating-point formats without subnormals, but with "hidden" 1 bits, how is/was 0 typically represented?
Was an entire binade reserved for it, or was 0x00000000 in the lowest binade reserved as a special case?
Or something else?
(I suppose I should try booting up my old PDP-11, and see...)

Answer (score 2):

From the *pdp11 processor handbook*, pdp11/04/24/34a/44/70, 1981, EB-19402-20, page 310:

> Because of the hidden bit, the fractional part is not available to distinguish between 0 and nonvanishing numbers whose fractional part is exactly ½. Therefore, the FP11 reserves a biased exponent of 0 for this purpose, and any floating point number with a biased exponent of 0 either traps or is treated as if it were an exact 0 in arithmetic operations. An exact or clean 0 is represented by a word whose bits are all 0s. A dirty 0 is a floating point number with a biased exponent of 0 and a nonzero fractional part.

It continues:

> An arithmetic operation for which the resulting true exponent exceeds 277<sub>8</sub> is regarded as producing a floating overflow; if the true exponent is less than −177<sub>8</sub>, the operation is regarded as produce a floating underflow. A biased exponent of 0 can thus arise from arithmetic operations as a special case of overflow (true exponent = −200<sub>8</sub>). Only eight bits are reserved for the biased exponent. The fractional part of results obtained from such overflow and underflow is correct.

The next paragraph describes any bit pattern with a sign bit of 1 and a biased exponent of 0 as an “undefined variable.” So there was no −0; that bit pattern would be a NaN.

Comment: "Dirty 0", eh?  That's certainly an evocative term!  (And while I can certainly appreciate that IEEE-754-style subnormals are a nuisance to implement, from a user's perspective they do seem much cleaner than this sort of thing!)

Answer (score 2):

**Example: entire binade reserved for it**

A not-so-old [FP format](https://www.ccsinfo.com/faq.php?page=mchp_float_format) with a hidden one bit treated the first byte as the biased exponent and when the biased exponent was 0, the value was 0.0, without consideration of the "23 bit mantissa".  I do not recall properties of a -0.0.

[CCS](https://www.ccsinfo.com) compilers used to use (~12 yrs ago) this for much of their FP, but now mostly use IEEE 754.

When non-zero, it was easy to removed the sign bit, "or" in the hidden 1 bit and process the value.

Comment: I wondered what the sign bit was doing there!  Cute.

Comment: This format was particularly useful with 8/16 embedded processors lacking a barrel shifter.  But was not popular enough to survive the Darwinian pressure of  IEEE 754.